# Run multiple RCP junit tests encompassed in multiple bundles

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have multiple RCP bundles and seperate fragment projects to test these bundles with either RCP plugin or plain jUnit tests.

**Problem**

To test the well functioning of the whole ecosystem we would like to run all tests from all plugins before we push new code to our CI environment.

Yet, till now we only figured out how to run the tests inside single projects at once. Thus, to run all tests on all plugins we currently select one plugin at a time and execute the tests inside via the context menu. This manual process is error-prone.

**Question**

Is there a way in the eclipse IDE to run all tests inside all plugin projects at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a Launch Group; you can find it under Debug Configurations.

Add all your existing JUnit (or JUnit Plug-in Test) launch configurations to it and then hit the Debug button.

Unfortunately if you create additional JUnit Plug-in tests after this Launch Group was created, then you have to add those new Plug-ins manually.